# AWS Amplify amplify-meta.json does not exist

Tags: ios, swift, aws-amplify

I'm following the steps to AWS Amplify docs for iOS (https://docs.amplify.aws/start/getting-started/installation/q/integration/ios/). And in the final step to `Connect to the Cloud` I get an error where the file path doesn't exist where amplify-meta.json is. I was wondering if someone understands how I can either generate or should I create this file? Thanks!

Looking up solutions on google.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The amplify-meta.json file is typically generated automatically by the Amplify CLI when you run `amplify init` or `amplify pull` command. This file contains metadata about your Amplify project and is used by the Amplify library to connect to your cloud resources.

If you're seeing an error that the `amplify-meta.json` file doesn't exist, it's possible that you either haven't run the amplify init command or there was an error during the initialization process.

To fix this, you can try running the `amplify init` command again and make sure to follow the prompts to configure your project correctly. You can also try running the `amplify pull` command if you've previously initialized your project and have cloud resources already configured.

If neither of these solutions works, you can try manually creating the `amplify-meta.json` file in your project directory and populating it with the necessary metadata.

Answer (score 0):

...or it might be that you have specified "src" as your root folder, so AWS has created a src folder and put it there.